# python tkinter add new buttons at runtime to scrollable frame

Tags: python, tkinter

the code below will add 10 buttons in scrollable frame
however what i want is to be able to add new buttons at anytime while the app is running
so i want it to add new buttons to the scrollable frame when ever i click any keyboard button however the code below doesn't do that and there is no error messages

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")

main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

for i in range(10):
    Button(second_frame, text=str(i)).grid(row=i, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

def onKeyPress(event):
        global second_frame
        print("key clicked")
        Button(second_frame, text='test').grid(row=10, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
        
root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It does add the button to the frame; it just doesn't adjust the scrollbar to fit the new button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is being added. However, you're not updating the `scrollregion` of the canvas so you can't see it because the frame becomes larger than the scrollable region.

One solution is to add one line to `onKeyPress`:

```
def onKeyPress(event):
    ...
    my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))
```

For a more general solution, you can instead add a binding to the `<Configure>` event of the inner frame, since that event fires whenever the frame grows or shrinks.

```
second_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
```

Comment: the more general solution did the job perfectly thank you